# How do I treat an element of a list as a column of dataframe for loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to treat the values in a list as column names to filter against in a for loop using R.  However, R seems to be treating the values as strings, not actual column names.  For example, let's say that I have a dataframe with 3 columns: PERSON_NAME, SCORE_1 and SCORE_2.  Then I store the "SCORE_1" and "SCORE_2" as values within as list.  I want to write a for loop that creates two data frames, one with students who scored >90 on the first exam and another with >90 on the second exam.

The following does it without a for loop.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a dataframe of test scores
df <- data.frame(
  PERSON_NAME = c('JIM', 'SALLY', 'JOHN', 'SUE'),
  SCORE_1 = c(100, 95, 80, 85),
  SCORE_2 = c(95, 75, 90, 97)
)

# Find students with SCORE_1 greater than 90
df %>%
  filter(
    SCORE_1 > 90
  ) %>%
  select(
    PERSON_NAME,
    SCORE_1
  )

# Find students with SCORE_2 greater than 90
df %>%
  filter(
    SCORE_2 > 90
  ) %>%
  select(
    PERSON_NAME,
    SCORE_2
  )
```

When I try a for loop, it doesn't seem to work.  I get two data frames with the right columns, however, the filtering is not working.  How do I adjust the below to make the filter step work?  Thank you!

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_tests)) {
  x <- df %>%
    filter(
      list_of_tests[i] > 90
    ) %>%
    select(
      PERSON_NAME,
      list_of_tests[i]
    )
  
  assign(list_of_tests[i],x)
}
```

Comment: Is the question specifically about for-loop or more about how one could split dataframe in described terms?

Comment: to @margusl - the question more focused on executing it in a for loop.  Specifically about how each element of the list can act as a column name to apply the filter against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
 map(threshold_cols, ~ df %>%
   filter(if_any(all_of(.x), ~ .x > 90)))
```

-output

```
$SCORE_1
  PERSON_NAME SCORE_1 SCORE_2
1         JIM     100      95
2       SALLY      95      75

$SCORE_2
  PERSON_NAME SCORE_1 SCORE_2
1         JIM     100      95
2         SUE      85      97
```

Comment: Looks like this is doing the trick.  I could store it as an object "x" and split using list2env(x,envir=.GlobalEnv)

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally solve this with `lapply()` & co in base R or with map-family functions from purrr:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  PERSON_NAME = c('JIM', 'SALLY', 'JOHN', 'SUE'),
  SCORE_1 = c(100, 95, 80, 85),
  SCORE_2 = c(95, 75, 90, 97)
)

list_of_tests <- list("SCORE_1", "SCORE_2")
names(list_of_tests) <- list_of_tests
lapply(list_of_tests, \(x) df[df[[x]] > 90, c("PERSON_NAME", x)])
#> $SCORE_1
#>   PERSON_NAME SCORE_1
#> 1         JIM     100
#> 2       SALLY      95
#> 
#> $SCORE_2
#>   PERSON_NAME SCORE_2
#> 1         JIM      95
#> 4         SUE      97
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>